# Determine transconductance of a JFET given only voltage gain and internal drain resistance

Tags: jfet, homework, transconductance

I have a homework question as follows:
If a JFET having a specified value of r<sub>d</sub>=100 kΩ has an ideal voltage gain of A<sub>v</sub>(FET) = -200,
what is the value of g<sub>m</sub> ?

As far as I know, the closest formula for g<sub>m</sub> relating A<sub>v</sub> and r<sub>d</sub> is A<sub>v</sub> = -g<sub>m</sub>(r<sub>d</sub>||R<sub>D</sub>)
but R<sub>D</sub> is not provided in the question. I would use R<sub>D</sub>=0Ω, but that would result in  <sup>1</sup>/<sub>(<sup>1</sup>/<sub>100kΩ</sub>)+(<sup>1</sup>/<sub>0Ω</sub>)</sub>, which is undefined. Is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Since we are talking about a JFET in isolation, A<sub>v</sub>=<sup>V<sub>DS</sub></sup>/<sub>V<sub>GS</sub></sub>

Since I<sub>D</sub>=g<sub>m</sub>*V<sub>GS</sub>, we can rearrange to
V<sub>GS</sub>=<sup>I<sub>D</sub></sup>/<sub>g<sub>m</sub></sub>
and since V<sub>GS</sub> is always negative, we can make this V<sub>GS</sub>=-<sup>I<sub>D</sub></sup>/<sub>g<sub>m</sub></sub>

lastly, since V<sub>DS</sub>=I<sub>D</sub>*r<sub>d</sub> we can plug these 2 equations into the first one to obtain
A<sub>v</sub>=I<sub>D</sub>*r<sub>d</sub>/-<sub>I<sub>D</sub>/<sub>g<sub>m</sub></sub></sub>

rearranging gives A<sub>v</sub>=-r<sub>d</sub>*g<sub>m</sub> which we can plug in -200 and 100kΩ to get a g<sub>m</sub>=2mS.

Comment: Let us know if there's anything else we can help you with.